# Given a string S and a string T, count the number of distinct subsequences of T in S

Tags: java, algorithm

Hi All: can someone explain to me how this algorithm works? I fail to understand the mechanism. Thanks.

Problem: Given a string S and a string T, count the number of distinct subsequences of T in S.

A subsequence of a string is a new string which is formed from the original string by deleting some (can be none) of the characters without disturbing the relative positions of the remaining characters. (ie, "ACE" is a subsequence of "ABCDE" while "AEC" is not).

Here is an example:
S = "rabbbit", T = "rabbit"

Return 3.

Solution:

```
public int numDistincts(String S, String T)
{
  int[][] table = new int[S.length() + 1][T.length() + 1];

  for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++)
      table[i][0] = 1;

  for (int i = 1; i <= S.length(); i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j <= T.length(); j++) {
          if (S.charAt(i - 1) == T.charAt(j - 1)) {
              table[i][j] += table[i - 1][j] + table[i - 1][j - 1];
          } else {
              table[i][j] += table[i - 1][j];
          }
      }
  }

  return table[S.length()][T.length()];
}
```

Comment: You might get a better response for this on cs.stackexchange.com or programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just try a dry run with your rabbbit example.

Answer (score 1):

The above DP solution using O(m*n) space, where m is the length of S, and n is the length of T. Below is the Solution that has only O(n) space.

```
public class Solution {  
    public int numDistinct(String s, String t) {  
        if(s == null || t == null || t.length() == 0) return 0;  
        int[] dp = new int[t.length()];  

        for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){  
            char c = s.charAt(i);  
            for(int j=dp.length-1; j>=0; j--){  
                if(c == t.charAt(j)){  
                    dp[j] = dp[j] + (j!=0?dp[j-1]: 1);  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        return dp[t.length()-1];  
    }  
}
```

From [this page](http://traceformula.blogspot.com/2015/08/distinct-subsequences.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that += can just as well be =, because each combination of [i][j] is visited only once - in fact = would be better because it wouldn't have to use the fact that in Java ints are initialised to 0.

This is a dynamic programming solution. table[i][j] ends up storing the answer when you consider only the first i characters of S and the first i characters of T.

The first loop says that if T is the zero length string the only subsequence of T in S is the zero length subsequence - there is one of these.

The second loop compares the ith character of S with the jth character of T at a time when these are both the last character of the short strings being dealt with. If these don't match the only subsequences of T in S are also sub-sequences of S with the last non-matching character chopped off, and we have already calculated these in table[i-1][j]. If they do match then there are extra subsequences that match this last character. If you take that last character off the subsequence then you find a subsequence from this segment of T with one character lopped off that matches one from S with one character lopped off, and you have already counted them in table[i-1][j-1] - so for a match the answer is table[i-1][j] + table[i-1][j-1].

At the end, of course, you find that you have calculated the answer for the full length of S and T in table[s.length][t.length]